# dynamically add options to a dropdown list that gets values from mysql database

Tags: php

I would like to add an option to a dropdown list without refreshing the form so that the other controls retain their values. I've tried looking for a tutorial but all I found are tutorials that dynamically populate a dropdown list with static options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the option with an AJAX call and then use DOM to add an option to your dropdown in the request callback.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate this task, I recommend using the jQuery library:
http://jquery.com/

Lookup the ajax function:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So you would have 2 pages,

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="default" selected="selected">Default option</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
              url: 'dropdown-choices.php',
              success: function(data) {
                $('#dropdown').append(data);
              }
            });                
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

dropdown-choices.php:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dropdown_choices;");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo '<option value="'+$data['value']+'">'+$data['name']+'</option>';
    }
?>
```

This should do it :)